# Any view in sql server filtered by date is very slow

Tags: sql-server-2008

In management studio 2008 R2 on Windows XP suddenly every view that I create and filter by Date is running very slow. For example on table of 10 rows, I filter by date and it takes 20 seconds to get the result.
When I run the query on sqlquery window it is running fast.
Same database on other computer working fast.
Is it a problem with OS ? I reinstalled the sql server - no help.

The query stuck during parsing stage - for example when I write >1/1/2017 on
filter column of the view and it takes 30 seconds until I see result in sql pane.

Comment: `Same database` ... but _same_ view?  AFAIK a view should perform no different than a query for the most part.  Do you have an index on the date column?

Comment: Any view on my computer, filtered by date started running slow

Comment: I this in Azure? I suggest you restart the SQL Server to clear any bad plans. How long does it take to get a query plan (CTRL-L).

Answer (score 1):

The view probably has a cached plan that is inefficient.

When you are running from SSMS it's probably being run as ad-hoc and generating a fresh plan.

Add the code

```
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

to the end of your view and see what happens.

Comment: The query stuck during parsing stage - for example when I write >1/1/2017 on filter column of the view and it takes 30 seconds until I see result in sql pane.

Comment: @alex gil: write your dates in the format '20170101' CCYYMMDD.

Answer (score 0):

At last I found a problem and the solution:

Short date format in regional options in computer was set to format: dd/MM/**yy**.

When I changed to dd/MM/**yyyy** - Date filtering started working fast.

I guess, I changed it previously without seeing the impact.

Comment: I would be very suprised if that was the reason